# Изменение HTML в WebView программно

Tags: java, webview

подскажите почему не работает замена значения value

хочу програмно изменить(поменять местами) пункты select на веб странице заменив значения value.

чтобы по дефолту был Basic

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Def = "Basic";
            String Bas = "Default";

            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('Default').value = '"+Def+"';})()");
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('Basic').value = '"+Bas+"';})()");

        }
    });
```

html код на странице

```
<select id="skinselector" name="RelayState" class="form-control"> 
<option value="Default" selected="selected">по умолчанию</option> 
<option value="Basic">Базовый</option> 
<option value="New">Новый</option></select>
```

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что вы ищите по имени тэга, а это, в вашем случае, `option`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, теперь работает
решил просто удалить 'selected="selected"' и присвоить заново

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил данную проблему

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.querySelector(\"#skinselector > option[selected]\").removeAttribute(\"selected\");})()");
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.querySelector(\"#skinselector > option[value='Basic']\").setAttribute(\"selected\", \"selected\");})()");

        }
    });
```

просто удаляю и присваиваю заново нужному пункту

> selected="selected"